# Why does debugging c++ using gdb in vscode create a an executable called launch.exe despite me specifying a name?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

When debugging a cpp file in Visual studio code the launch.json seems to be making a launch.exe even though I specified in the tasks that the output file should be called "main.exe" and on top of that there's a build error yet the executable made runs correctly.

All files are in the same directory and the only folder in this directory is the automatically generated .vscode folder
My task.json :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\main.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {"kind" : "build","isDefault": true},
            "detail": "compiler: \"C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe\""
        }
       
    ]
}
```

My launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\main.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

And then the actual cpp files :
main.cpp

```
#include "Log.h"

int main()
{
    Log("Hello World");
}
```

Log.cpp

```
#include "Log.h"
#include <iostream>
void Log(const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message << "!\n";
}
```

And a header file
Log.h

```
#pragma once
void Log(const char* message);
```

What I expect to happen is that the tasks.json gets all the cpp files compiled and linked then creates an executable called main.exe.

This does happen when I just run the build task through Terminal > Run Build Task...  but when I try debugging by pressing F5 when on my main.cpp file, there is a build error and, in my directory, a launch.exe executable is created. I am then prompted that there were build errors and after clicking "debug anyway", a prompt appears showing that "main.exe" does not exist.
The build error :

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUAuPNe.o: In function `main':
c:/Users/Me/Projects/test/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Log(char const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
```

My platform is windows and
I believe I have all the necessary extensions installed correctly so I don't really understand what causes this issue.

It does debug correctly when I change the "program" value in launch.json to "${fileDirname}\launch.exe" (although there is still the build error) but why is launch.exe being made and why are there build errors when debugging but no build errors when going through Terminal > Run Build Task... ?

Comment: if you use more than 1 `.cpp` file you have to use a build tool (Make variants), clean your directory of all stuff generated (`*.o` and `*.exe`) and build again.